# Pass jquery date into hidden input

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to populate three hidden INPUT fields, that when the form is posted, will transfer to an external form.  That external form will read what I post.  I need the three hidden inputs to be filled with the current month, day, & year.  Right now, when I post, they come in blank.

I have about 120+ fields in this form that work fine, just not the three below.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

```
<input type="hidden" id="currmonth" name="currmonth"/>
<input type="hidden" id="currday" name="currday"/>
<input type="hidden" id="curryear" name="curryear"/>


$(document).ready(function () {
        function getDates(){
            var currday = new Date();
            var currday= currdate.getDate();
            var currmonth = new Date();
            var currmonth= (currdate.getMonth()+ 1);
            var curryear = new Date();
            var curryear= currdate.getFullYear();   

            $("#currday").val(currday);
            $("#currmonth").val(currmonth);
            $("#curryear").val(curryear);               
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to call `getDates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters you are referencing a undefined object in your code. You are saying for example `var currday= currdate.getDate();` where there are no initiation of `currdate`.

Secondly, you are simply creating the function `getDates()`, and never referencing it. The function will never be called, and those fields will never be populated, even if you had referenced the correct `Date`-object.

An example would be to do the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
         
        getDates();

    });

function getDates(){
    var currdate = new Date();
    
    var currday= currdate.getDate();
    var currmonth= (currdate.getMonth()+ 1);
    var curryear= currdate.getFullYear();   
    
    $("#currday").val(currday);
    $("#currmonth").val(currmonth);
    $("#curryear").val(curryear);               
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" id="currmonth" name="currmonth"/>
<input type="hidden" id="currday" name="currday"/>
<input type="hidden" id="curryear" name="curryear"/>
```